# JObject calculating path

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am using Newton-King Json library for C#

I am looping through a json object and rendering the object into html, is there anyway of calculating the path of where I am in the entire json object, ie data.vehicles[0].car[0].Name?

Thanks for all  your help

Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `Path` property? http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm